# Spring Security roles are not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have configured spring security in my app,authentication is working well but authorization is not working mean `@secured()` annotation is not working.i am getting error when i access url "There was an unexpected error `(type=Forbidden, status=403)`.
Access is denied".

My spring config is

```
@Autowired
    private MongoDBAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/resource")
                .and().logout().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
```

My controller is

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Secured(value={"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getUser() {
        System.out.println("working");
    }
}
```

Database user is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555982a5360403572551660c"), "username" : "user", "password" : "pass", "role" : "ADMIN" }
```

My mongodb auth provider

```
@Service
public class MongoDBAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider{


    @Autowired
    MongoUserDetailsService mongoUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        UserDetails loadedUser;

        try {
            loadedUser = mongoUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        } catch (Exception repositoryProblem) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(repositoryProblem.getMessage(), repositoryProblem);
        }

        if (loadedUser == null) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(
                    "UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation");
        }
        return loadedUser;
    }
}
```

User domain

```
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;




    public User() {
        super();        
    }



    public User(String name,String username,
            String password, String role) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }



    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }


    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }



    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a role **ADMIN** not **ROLE_ADMIN**. Either fix your `@Secured` expression or change the user in the database. Also `hasRole` prefixes with `ROLE_`.

Comment: you mean i should have to write  @Secured(value={"ADMIN"}) ?

Comment: please post the full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Add this bean in Spring Security Config File

```
    @Bean
    public RoleVoter roleVoter() {
        RoleVoter roleVoter = new RoleVoter();
        roleVoter.setRolePrefix("");
        return roleVoter;
    }
```

And write secured annotation like this

```
       @Secured(value={"ADMIN"})
```

Comment: i added this one to spring config file like roleVoter.setRolePrefix("ROLE_"); . but it is not working

Comment: By Deafault prefix is "ROLE_" 
So you have to change either in database or set prefix to ""

Comment: Hey i think i doing something wrong,could you please tell me how to do this with full description ?

Comment: @PrabjotSingh Please share your mongoDb auth provider and also User class if any

Answer (score 0):

```
@Secured(value={"ADMIN"})
```

Instead of

```
@Secured(value={"ROLE_ADMIN"})
```

You also could try

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

If @Secured annotation still doesn't work